# Showing two groups have the same frequency distribution

Tags: chi-squared-test, frequency, type-i-and-ii-errors

I have two groups of the frequency at which 4 events happened and I am testing if they are from the same population. I used a chi squared goodness of fit test with expected value related to their average frequency (which would minimize the chi squared test statistic). The chi squared test statistic was below the critical value for 3 degrees of freedom and alpha=0.05 so I reject the alternate hypothesis that they are different. Now I would like to know that the probability that I have made a type two error is below 0.05 but I do not know of a test which can do this.

Is there a test which can be used where the null hypothesis is that the two frequency groups are different and the alternate hypothesis is that the two groups are the same? If I could use that test to show that they are the same at a level alpha=0.05 then the chance of making a type 2 error in my original case would be sufficiently low.

Comment: "Different" isn't a useful hypothesis.  The two groups can be as close as you like & still be different, so no test will ever reject it. The power function of the test shows the probability of making a Type II error for a given degree of difference.